# How to search for a line from a string knowing only the keyword and then delete it?

Tags: javascript

I have the following string:

```
var myString =
"  
ALTER TABLE "barakuda".Table1 ADD xyz NUMBER NULL;
ALTER TABLE "barakuda".Table1 ADD tmp NUMBER NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE "barakuda".Table1 ADD CONSTRAINT Table1_PK PRIMARY KEY (tmp);
ALTER TABLE "barakuda".Table1 ADD data NUMBER NULL;
ALTER TABLE "barakuda".Table1 ADD newtmp NUMBER NOT NULL; 
"
```

What i want to do:

**1. Find key word "PRIMARY KEY"**

[image]

**2. Delete entire row**

[image]

**3. Final result**

[image]

Can someone give me some advice how to achieve such a thing? My JS skills are... ekhem
Well i know method `split()` but i have no idea how achieve that result. I know the key here is character `;` because it is splitting rows.

Comment: can you please post your code where you are facing the issue ?

Comment: Did you read my post? Images of code helps to understand my point. I don't see anything wrong in my post...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use of a RegExp.

Use https://regex101.com/ to understands the details of the following :

```js
const myString = `  
ALTER TABLE "barakuda".Table1 ADD xyz NUMBER NULL;
ALTER TABLE "barakuda".Table1 ADD tmp NUMBER NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE "barakuda".Table1 ADD CONSTRAINT Table1_PK PRIMARY KEY (tmp);
ALTER TABLE "barakuda".Table1 ADD data NUMBER NULL;
ALTER TABLE "barakuda".Table1 ADD newtmp NUMBER NOT NULL; 
`;

const ret = myString.replace(/.*PRIMARY KEY.*;(\s)*/ig, '');

console.log(ret);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do it like this:

```js
    let myString = 'alter table\n'+ 
    'alter tabel next line\n'+
    'alter table PRIMARY KEY\n'+
    'alter table PRIMARY KEY\n'+
    'alter tabel next line\n'+
    'alter tabel next line\n'+
    'alter tabel next line\n'+
    'last line';
    
    let result = myString.replace(/^.*PRIMARY KEY.*$/mg, "");
    console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it can help you:

```js
var myString = `
ALTER TABLE "barakuda".Table1 ADD xyz NUMBER NULL;
ALTER TABLE "barakuda".Table1 ADD tmp NUMBER NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE "barakuda".Table1 ADD CONSTRAINT Table1_PK "PRIMARY KEY" (tmp);
ALTER TABLE "barakuda".Table1 ADD data NUMBER NULL;
ALTER TABLE "barakuda".Table1 ADD newtmp NUMBER NOT NULL; 
`;

let stringsArray = myString.split("\n")
let newMyStringWithoutPrimaryKey = stringsArray.filter(str =>
    !str.includes("PRIMARY KEY"),
).join("\n")
```

Comment: let output = myString.split("\n").filter(str => !str.includes("PRIMARY KEY").join("\n");

Comment: Gregory was first but your way is really simple and nice, thanks man!

Answer (score 1):

An example using findIndex and splice instead of filter

```js
const myStrings = `ALTER TABLE "barakuda".Table0 ADD xyz NUMBER NULL;
ALTER TABLE "barakuda".Table1 ADD tmp NUMBER NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE "barakuda".Table2 ADD CONSTRAINT Table1_PK PRIMARY KEY (tmp);
ALTER TABLE "barakuda".Table3 ADD data NUMBER NULL;
ALTER TABLE "barakuda".Table4 ADD newtmp NUMBER NOT NULL;`.split("\n")

const indx = myStrings.findIndex(ele => ele.includes("PRIMARY KEY"))
if (index !=-1) myStrings.splice(indx,1)
console.log(myStrings)
```